Can women preform miracles?
1 Timothy 2:15 (ESV)

15 Yet she will be saved through childbearing—if they continue in
faith and love and holiness, with self-control.

Scripture says women are saved through childbearing. It also shows no women in the Bible preformed a miracle. Can they carry out a ministry of miracles? They can prophesy, but are they allowed to preform miracles?

sorry your question was closed on a technicality. However it was asked and answered here. Looks like Jason also snuck an answer in here. It seems like the only woman who performed a miracle in the OT was the medium of Endor. who resurrected the spirit of King Saul (but this was not a good miracle - similar to Pharaoh's magicians creating a snake from a staff).

A type of "miracle" that was not mentioned is the heroic acts of Jael in Judges and Judith in the apocrypha of semi-miraculously killing enemy leaders, which they accomplished with God's help. The story of Tamar's twins is also miraculous, but did she perform it?

Note also that your proof text for this question is a difficult verse on which experienced scholars have a range of interpretations. We need to be very cautious about basing our theology on such a verse.

The short answer is that the Bible does not explicitly describe a woman performing a miracle. At least, not in the same manner as the prophets or Jesus. On the other hand, women were often instrumental in God’s plan and witnessed or facilitated miraculous events. For example:

Mary, the mother of Jesus, is one of the central women in the New
Testament who was part of a very significant miracle. According to the
Gospel of Luke, Mary conceived Jesus through the Holy Spirit, which
is one of the foundational miracles of Christianity (Luke 1:26-38).
Deborah, a prophetess and judge, played a key role in the victory
over the Canaanites, which was a miraculous deliverance for Israel
(Judges 4-5).
Esther’s courage led to the miraculous deliverance of the Jewish
people from a plot to destroy them (The Whole Book of Esther).

Jesus’ ministry included interactions with women, and many of His miracles involved women either as recipients or witnesses. For instance, Jesus healed a woman who had been bleeding for twelve years, which is considered one of His many miracles (Mark 5:25-34).
Furthermore, the early church saw the outpouring of the Holy Spirit at Pentecost. Scripture says that both men and women receive the gift of the Spirit and shall prophesy.
Acts 2:17-18

17 ‘And it shall come to pass in the last days, says God, That I will
pour out of My Spirit on all flesh; Your sons and your daughters shall
prophesy, Your young men shall see visions, Your old men shall dream
dreams. 18 And on My menservants and on My maidservants I will pour
out My Spirit in those days; And they shall prophesy.

Additionally, the New Testament does not place gender restrictions on the gifts of the Spirit, which happens to include miracles (1 Corinthians 12:7-11).

7 But the manifestation of the Spirit is given to each one for the
profit of all: 8 for to one is given the word of wisdom through the
Spirit, to another the word of knowledge through the same Spirit, 9 to
another faith by the same Spirit, to another gifts of healings by
the same Spirit, 10 to another the working of miracles, to another
prophecy, to another discerning of spirits, to another different kinds
of tongues, to another the interpretation of tongues. 11 But one and
the same Spirit works all these things, distributing to each one
individually as He wills.

What then can we conclude? While the Bible does not explicitly describe a woman performing a miracle in the same way as Jesus or the apostles, women were certainly involved in miraculous events and played very pivotal roles in God’s redemptive work and miraculous events. Finally, the New Testament teachings on spiritual gifts suggest that all believers, including women, can be used by God to perform miracles.

Many women were prophets - a very miraculous work indeed.  Loom at Deborah and the four daughters of Philip among others.
